# MySQL union is not working with insert and select statement

Tags: mysql, insert, mariadb, union

I want to make a SQL script to fetch data from multiple tables and insert into one table

Below sub queries working fine

1. When run them one by one in **INSERT** statement
2. Both select queries are working fine with union when i am not using them in insert query.

but when i am using **UNION** to make it a single script then it gives me `syntax error`.

```
INSERT INTO cfx_subscriptions ( cfx_account_id, isv_company_id, license_qty, `status`, created_on, 
subscription_start_date, subscription_end_date, subscription_id, modified_on, product_id) 
(
    SELECT s.idp_account_id, '', 1 AS quantity,
    (CASE 
        WHEN s.activation_status = 1 THEN 'active' 
        WHEN s.activation_status = 2 THEN 'suspended' 
        WHEN s.activation_status = 3 THEN 'deleted' 
        ELSE ''
    END) AS 'status', CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME( s.creation_date / 1000) AS DATETIME ) AS created_on,
    CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME( s.creation_date / 1000) AS DATETIME ) AS subscription_start_date, 
    s.expiry_date, s.sage_company_id, s.updated_date, s.portal_product_id FROM cfx_sage_subscriptions s 
UNION   
SELECT os.idp_account_id, c.id, os.quantity, os.`status`, cast(os.creationDate as DATETIME) AS created_on, 
    cast(os.effectiveStartDate as DATETIME) AS subscription_start_date, cast(os.commitmentEndDate as DATETIME) AS commitmentEndDate,
    os.subscriptionId, cast(os.creationDate as DATETIME) AS modified_on, TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM SUBSTR(os.cloudselect_product_id,4))
        FROM cfx_office365_customer_order_subscriptions  os
        JOIN cfx_office365_customer c ON os.tenantId=c.companyProfile_tenantId

)
```

Below is the error produce by above first script

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try avoiding alias in select result

```
INSERT INTO cfx_subscriptions ( cfx_account_id, isv_company_id, license_qty, `status`, created_on, 
subscription_start_date, subscription_end_date, subscription_id, modified_on, product_id) 
    SELECT s.idp_account_id, '', 1 ,
    (CASE 
        WHEN s.activation_status = 1 THEN 'active' 
        WHEN s.activation_status = 2 THEN 'suspended' 
        WHEN s.activation_status = 3 THEN 'deleted' 
        ELSE ''
    END) , CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME( s.creation_date / 1000) AS DATETIME ) ,
    CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME( s.creation_date / 1000) AS DATETIME ) , 
    s.expiry_date, s.sage_company_id, s.updated_date, s.portal_product_id 
    FROM cfx_sage_subscriptions s 
UNION   
SELECT os.idp_account_id, c.id, os.quantity, os.`status`, cast(os.creationDate as DATETIME) , 
    cast(os.effectiveStartDate as DATETIME) , cast(os.commitmentEndDate as DATETIME) ,
    os.subscriptionId, cast(os.creationDate as DATETIME) , TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM SUBSTR(os.cloudselect_product_id,4))
        FROM cfx_office365_customer_order_subscriptions  os
        JOIN cfx_office365_customer c ON os.tenantId=c.companyProfile_tenantId
```